# Two quartic polynomials to be made a square?

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-curves, rational-numbers

Given two generally *non-square* quartic polynomials that are to be *simultaneously* made squares for particular values of $x$,

$$c_1x^4+c_2x^3+c_3x^2+c_4x+c_5 = y_1^2$$

$$c_6x^4+c_7x^3+c_8x^2+c_9x+c_{10} = y_2^2$$

where the $c_i$ are rational constants.

**Q: Is it proven that there can only be a *finite* number of rational $x,y_i$?**

This problem sometimes arises in systems of equal sums of like powers. For example,

$$\begin{aligned}&(b - p)^k+(a + b + p)^k+(-a + b + p)^k+(2 + b - p)^k+(-2 + c)^k=\\
&(b + p)^k+(-a + b - p)^k+(a + b - p)^k+(-2 + b + p)^k+( 2 + c)^k\end{aligned}$$

which is good for $k = 1,3,5,7$, if,

$$2p+4 = a^2\tag{1}$$

$$p^2+3p-1 = 3b^2\tag{2}$$

$$10p^2+21p-1 = 3c^2\tag{3}$$

It is easy to satisfy the first condition, but the other two now become quartics to be made squares. There are an infinite number of non-trivial rational $p$ that simultaneously solve (1) and (2), OR (1) and (3), OR (2) and (3), but I would like to know if there are an *infinite* number of such $p$ that simultaneously satisfy all three.

Comment: Consider the case that one of the LHSes is a square polynomial...

Comment: I'll rephrase the first line...

Comment: A computation using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula suggests that generically (if the two quartic polynomials are relatively prime and have distinct roots) your equations define a curve of genus $5$, which has finitely many rational points by Faltings' theorem, but I'm too lazy to check whether the variety is smooth.